# Div position changed when text is added

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make three sections using divs.

Here is an image of what I currently have:

[image]

When I add text to the middle div, the div shifts down like this:

[image]

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">sometext</div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#left{
    width: 610px;
    height: 1065px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #636363;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#middle{
    width: 625px;
    height: 1065px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #636363;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right{
    width: 610px;
    height: 1065px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #636363;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `#wrapper div { vertical-align: top; }` would do it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `overflow: hidden;` to your divs.

Example:

```
#middle {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 625px;
    height: 1065px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #636363;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You may also set it to `overflow: auto` if you want the container to be scrollable if the text reaches the bottom.

Another, more common approach is to use CSS's [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

You could then style your div's like this:

```
div {
    float: left;
    width: 625px;
    height: 1065px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #636363;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
```

See an example [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WQZ6L/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried using floats at the beginning but it did not worked out. Now it does !

Comment: Glad it worked out @user2626159. You can read up on the link I provided, good luck! :)

Comment: I guess I didn't apply the float:left to all div's.