# Changing innerText causing DIV overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While inserting Text into a div,I found a problem that div position keep change and div's are overlapping to another div.For more details

[Before inserting text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1JPh.png)

following style -

```css
.cell {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Then after doing the following

```js
$('#cell_1').text('x');
$('#cell_1').text('0');
```

[this happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXqOv.png)

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902102/div-position-changed-when-text-is-added) I got to know that

> overflow:hidden;

will solve my problem. But I really want to know how a single text character causing the overflow? what is actually happening behind the scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about DOM reflow / repaint. Setting `overflow: hidden;` to the element in that case will force browser to recalculate it's geometry. 
It's a big theme and it's necessary to know. It will also explain you why `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` triggers the height of container with `float` elements inside.

Long read here:
https://sites.google.com/site/getsnippet/javascript/dom/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom-responsibly